# SonarQube Eclipse plugin: incremental mode for changed files only

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I'm using the SonarQube Eclipse plugin v. 3.4.0, against a SonarQube Server v. 4.5.5 to analyze Java sources on several projects.

The server analysis runs on a daily basis, against the latest sources from our Source Control Manager.

As expected, whenever I perform an analysis using the SonarQube Eclipse plugin, it runs in incremental mode, i.e., it analyzes only the source files on my workspace which **differ** from the source files that were used on the last Server analysis.

The problem is that I would like to have the plugin analyze **only the source files I have changed on my workspace**, and not all the files that differ between the workspace and server.

I'm on the process of adopting SonarQube for our entire development team, whose projects are very dynamic (about 100 source files per day added/changed). The goal is to have every developer see only the **new SonarQube issues** that he has added, whenever it runs a local analysis using the plugin. But since it is highly likely that the set of sources each developer holds on his own workspace differs from the set of sources used during the server analysis, he will always end up seeing issues that were not added by him.

Is is possible to have the SonarQube plugin analyze only the source files from the workspace that differ from the server **and were changed**, for example, by looking at the read-only file attribute?

Comment: Isn't it what the incremental mode does? It analyse the file changed since the last server run. If your developers use separate workspaces each will see only his own issues.

Comment: Incremental mode would do that if the files from local workspaces were obtained from the Source Control Manager **at the same time** as the files used during the last Server Analysis. Each file change the user didn't get from SCM will be considered a difference.

Answer (score 0):

That's something we are wanting to implement, unfortunately there is no magic way to implement that AFAIK. Several options: timestamp, local cache, SCM status, ... but all may have some problems (especially performance issues).